# Database insert error (Qt,sqlite)

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite

I seek help for this issue I couldn't find an answer anywhere. I have a program that loads multiple string variables and then I am trying to paste them into a sqlite3 database, everything seems good, I have a conection, but this piece of code gives me an error : expected ';' before string constant (it asks for it before the farba variable. Any ideas?

```
QSqlQuery query;
query.exec("INSERT INTO spz VALUES") "(Meno,Priezvisko,Datum,Bydlisko,COP,Znacka,Model,Farba,Objem,Rok,SPZ) VALUES('"  meno  "','"  priezvisko  "','"  vek  "','"  bydlisko  "','"  cop  "','"  vyrobca  "','"  model  "','"  farba  "','"  objem  "','"  rok  "','"  znacka"');");
```

Comment: Does that string look right to you?

Comment: I now see that I've messed it up but even the below mentioned code does not work for me.

Comment: What I sometimes do is create the string in a variable before calling the `query.exec()` function. That way you can print it out to see if it is building correctly.

Comment: Some of your variables that you are putting into database fields may contain characters that can upset the `SQL` string. For example if they contain quotes. So you may need to *escape* some of your fields. Printing the `SQL` out should highlight such problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
QSqlQuery query;
query.exec("INSERT INTO spz(Meno,Priezvisko,Datum,Bydlisko,COP,Znacka,Model,Farba,Objem,Rok,SPZ) VALUES('" + meno + "','" + priezvisko + "','"  + vek + "','" + bydlisko + "','" + cop + "','" + vyrobca + "','" + model + "','" + farba + "','" + objem + "','" + rok  "','" + znacka +"');");
```

**Other Method:**

```
QSqlQuery query;
query.prepare("INSERT INTO spz(Meno,Priezvisko,Datum,Bydlisko,COP,Znacka,Model,Farba,Objem,Rok,SPZ) VALUES (:meno, :priezvisko, :vek, :bydlisko, :cop, :vyrobca, :model, :farba, :objem, :rok, :znacka)");
query.bindValue(":meno", meno);
query.bindValue(":vek", vek);
query.bindValue(":bydlisko", bydlisko);
query.bindValue(":cop", cop);
query.bindValue(":vyrobca", vyrobca);
query.bindValue(":model", model);
query.bindValue(":farba", farba);
query.bindValue(":objem", objem);
query.bindValue(":rok", rok);
query.bindValue(":znacka", znacka);
query.exec();
```

Comment: Thank you, but this one gave back Incopatible types string and integer because of the + char.

Comment: I don't know the datatypes of meno, priezvisko, vek, ... variables. You need to make the proper casting for each datatype.

Comment: also the datatypes are all string. If you dont mind me asking, what do you mean by proper casting?

Comment: I thought that the parameters are not of string data type. I added another method that will let you avoid string concatenation. both should work for you. Please mention the error message you got if you still have issue with my code.

Comment: Now, the first line is ok, while the other gave :   error: no matching function for call to 'QSqlQuery::bindValue(const char [6], std::string&)'
     query.bindValue(":meno", meno);
                                  ^

Comment: std::string to query.bindValue(), but it expects a QString. you can try converting each variable before passing for example: QString vv = meno.c_str();query.bindValue(":meno", vv);

Comment: Also can convert to string like so, QString vv=QString::fromStdString(your_std_string);